# The Distribution of Partial Sum $S_n = \sum_i i \times a_i$, where $a_i$ is a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

I think I got stuck with this question:

$\{a_i\}， i=1,2,\cdots$ $i.i.d.$ to Binary $（\pm 1， p=1/2）$

and I would like to know how to calculate the de distribution of $S_n$

where $S_n = \sum^{n}_{i=1} i \cdot a_i$

To be frank, I have no idea where I should start this question.

I think numerically, as everybody in physics departement, I would try to simulate with a Gaussian distribution. But I doubt if this is correct.....

Comment: Try computing the distribution for $n=2,3$ and see if you find a pattern that you can prove by induction. If not, this isn't likely to have a nice closed form.

Comment: Looking at characteristic function, we see that it's $\phi_{n}(t) = \prod_{k=1}^n \cos(kt)$, but I really doubt one can tell more about the distribution. This can be (the product) written in a form using pochhammer symbol/function, but it ain't telling more than this product